# Does dhtmlxcommon.js should load for each dhtmx components in a document

Tags: dhtmlx

I am using multiple dhtmlx components in my application. There is a seperate dhtmlxcommon.js file is exist for each component in it's folder. If I use multiple components in single page should I load dhtmlxcommon.js files for each and every component?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to load one dhtmlxcommon.js file.